# Adding Items from Dialog Box to ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am having some trouble adding values entered in a dialog box into a listview. What I have is a home screen with two listviews and two buttons, each list view has a button that when pressed will open a dialog box. The dialog box will ask the user for information and when closed this information will be added into the listview.

I am having trouble adding the items to the ListView and cant seem to see where I have gone wrong. I can open the dialog boxes, enter the data and close the box but the text isnt being added into the listview.

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button ingredient;
    private Button direction;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView ingredientList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsList);
        final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);

        ingredientList.setAdapter(adapter);

        ingredient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showIngredientDialog);
        ingredient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // custom ingredient_dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ingredient_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Add Ingredient");

                // set the custom ingredient_dialog components
                final EditText ingredient = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
                //ingredient.getText().toString();

                Spinner measurement = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.measurement);
                String measurementValue = measurement.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Spinner unit = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.unit);
                String unitValue = unit.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom ingredient_dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        arrayList.add(ingredient.getText().toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        direction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDirectionDialog);
        direction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // custom ingredient_dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.direction_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Add Step");

                // set the custom ingredient_dialog components
                TextView description = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.description);
                EditText ingredient = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.direction);

                Button dialogButton2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom ingredient_dialog
                dialogButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Activity_main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe"
        android:text="New Recipe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientsList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recipe"
        android:layout_above="@+id/showIngredientDialog">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showIngredientDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Ingredient"
        android:layout_above="@+id/showDirectionDialog"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="145dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/directionList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/showDirectionDialog"
        android:layout_below="@+id/showIngredientDialog"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/showIngredientDialog">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showDirectionDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Direction"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ingredient_dialog.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="e.g Onions"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/measurement"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:entries="@array/measurements"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/measurement"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:entries="@array/units"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are closing the dialog on clicking on ok button then the views will be no longer live. So get the data first from the view and dismiss the dialog

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                        arrayList.add(ingredient.getText().toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but that didnt seem to fix it, the list is still showing up blank

Comment: I have just noticed that I was using the wrong layout for the list, used a simple spinner and not simple_list_item_1. Thanks again for you help, I wouldnt have seen that mistake